# How to use jquery prepend() function for adding rupee symbol before all numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am trying to add Rupee Symbol before the numbers. If there is "-" then i don't want to add the Rupee symbol over there. here is my code  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Hrac3/1/)

```
var te = $('p.active').text();
    var te2 = $('p.in_active').text();    
    if(te === '-'){}
    else{$('p.active').prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");}
    if(te2 === '-'){}
    else{$('p.in_active').prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");}
```

My Html Is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.webrupee.com/font" />
<div class="main">
<p class="active">10,200</p>
<p class="in_active">1,68,10,900</p>
<p class="active">0</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">12,78,200</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">-</p>
<p class="in_active">9,890</p>
<p class="active">10,200</p>
<p class="in_active">1,68,10,900</p>
<p class="active">0</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">12,78,200</p>
<p class="in_active">-</p>
<p class="active">-</p>
<p class="in_active">9,890</p>
</div>​
```

my css is

```
.in_active{color:#999;font-size:11pt;font-weight:400;}
.active{color:#333;font-size:11pt;font-weight:400;}
.main{padding:30px;}​
```

Comment: I hope this is not for India. Indian Rupee symbol is changed. It is not Rs. anymore. Just an FYI :)

Comment: Oh I guess, cdn.webruppe.com is doing that magic. Sorry for my ignorance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make sense to loop through the paragraphs instead. How about:

```
$('.active, .in_active').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).text() != '-' ) {
        $(this).prepend('<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('p.active').prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");` selects every active paragraph and prepends the Rs. symbol. You want to use a loop instead, which checks for every paragraph whether the prepend should take place or not. For example, here's what you could do:

```
$('p.active, p.in_active').each(function() {
     if($(this).text() !== '-') {
        $(this).prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");
    }
});
```

Also note that you can have several classes per element, which means that you can have one single classe for every `<p>` in your exemple: `<p class="rupee in_active">1,68,10,900</p>` versus `<p class="active">10,200</p>`. If all elements with the "rupee" class should have the Rupee symbol prepended, then you can simply write:

```
$('p.rupee').prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");
```

Comment: `$('p.active', 'p.in_active')` looks for `p.active` in the context of `p.in_active`. Is the same as `$('p.in_active').find('p.active');`. See: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.in_active').each(function(){
var hyphen = $(this).html();
if(hyphen == '-'){

}else{
   $(this).prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");
}
});
```

Comment: its only example let the user do something on his own

Answer (score 1):

Please check this working example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTN2E/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main p").each(function(){
          var pValue = $(this).text();
            if(pValue != '-'){
               $(this).prepend("<span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");
            }

        });

    });
```